# How can I account for missing values in a dataframe obtained from webscrapped data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I webscrapped a website using BeautifulSoup to obtain student_names, email and professors. However, some student_mames have no email addresses so after joining/concat the data,the total number of rows reduced to account for missing emails in the dataframe. Also, there is a mismatch between student_names and email_addresses. Is there a way to account for the missing email addresses during webscraping or while forming the dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
    with open('Biology.html') as file:
scrapped_data=[]
soup=BeautifulSoup(file)
name=soup.find_all('strong')
full_name=[]
for i in name:
    full_name.append(i.text)
full_name=full_name[:-1]
supervisors=soup.find_all('div',class_='person-job-titles')
supervisor_list=[]
for m in supervisors:
    supervisor_list.append(m.contents[0].split(":")[-1].strip())
emails=soup.find_all('a',href=re.compile('^mailto'))
email_add=[]
for j in emails:
    email_add.append(j.attrs['title'])   
scrapped_data.append({'Names':full_name,'Supervisors': supervisor_list,'Emails': email_add})
df=pd.DataFrame(scrapped_data,columns=['Names','Supervisors','Emails'])
```

Comment: We need more info on how the HTML is structured. Is there a way to link which emails belong to which student within the HTML?

Comment: Yes I think so. They are all inside the same <td class. Can I send you an image or something? I don't know how to describe it here.

Comment: Take a look at the Stackoverflow guidelines on questions. Specifically the section on 'Help others reproduce the problem.' https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It will help us help you resolve the issue :)